# Open WebView not browser from preferenceScreen Android

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

From my PreferenceScreen I want to open links in WebView not browser. Any ideas?

Here is part of my xml:

```
 <PreferenceCategory
      android:title="@string/about">
     <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/eula"
            android:summary="">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://www.tara.com/m/EULA.aspx" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/privacy_policy"
            android:summary="">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://www.tara.com/m/Legal/Privacy.aspx" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/version"
            android:summary="@string/version_name">
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/customer_support"
            android:summary="@string/email_description">
            <intent android:action="com.tara.android.turboweather.EMAIL_ACCUWX"
             />
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/branding"
            android:summary="">
    </PreferenceScreen>        
</PreferenceCategory>
```

So where the URLs are I want to open an Android WebView, not open the phone's browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should the use a click listener on your preference item and when it s clicked, open your activity.

in XMl, replace the PreferenceScreen by a Preference and give it a key

```
<Preference android:title="About"
            android:summary="Details about the app"
            android:key="aboutPref" />
```

then in your preference activity, after loading the preference file :

```
Preference pref = findPreference( "aboutPref" );
pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener( myListener );
```

where myListener is an instance of an inner class that will launch your activity and pass the url to open in intent extra data.

Regards,
 Stéphane